# how to Sequelize "where" accessing table and column

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I am attempting to port an application that had used sequelize 3.30.4 and I'm updating to 6.13, I'm assuming some things have changed because I can't use string literals in a where clause, or so the debugger tells me.

That said, I've done some googling and have found some basic examples that make sense sure but I'm not entirely sure how to convert this string to a format acceptable for findAndCountAll to be happy.

I've attempted something like this, thinking it might at least point me in the right direction however it does not.

```js
  let attributes = ['id', 'name', 'locationId'];
  let where = undefined;
  let order = [['name', 'ASC']];

    where = {
      classroom: {
        locationId: request.query.locationId
      }
    }
```

this is the line that did at one time work but no longer works.

```js
where = `"classroom"."locationId" = ${request.query.locationId}`;
```

```js
  const classrooms = await model.classroom.findAndCountAll(_.assign({},
    requestHelper.computePaginationObject(request.query.limit, request.query.page), {
    attributes,
    where: where ? [where] : undefined,
    order
  }));
```

how would I go about porting this into the proper format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
let where = {}
if (<some condition>) {
  where = {
    locationId: request.query.locationId
  }
}
const classrooms = await model.classroom.findAndCountAll(_.assign({},
    requestHelper.computePaginationObject(request.query.limit, request.query.page), {
    attributes,
    where: where,
    order
  }));
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I see what I did wrong.

I did have it incased in an if block, but the issue lay in that I didn't realize I was already accessing the classroom table, I was trying to structure it as the old line read. Eg. classroom.locationId,

but since it's already referencing that table all I needed was the location Id. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try that even if the first comment of **ANATOLY** works wonders :

```
const where = <some condition> ? {locationId: request.query.locationId} :{};

const classrooms = await model.classroom.findAndCountAll(_.assign({},
        requestHelper.computePaginationObject(request.query.limit, request.query.page), {
        attributes,
        where,
        order
      }));
```